# post_operations {} or config { type: "operations"} in GCP Dataform

Tags: dataform

A question about choosing between utilising `post_operations {}` to execute a SQL statement after an incremental table creation or creating another operation type `config { type: "operations"}` in GCP Dataform.

The goal is to update a column in the incremental data right after the new incremental records merge into the incremental table. Both incremental table sql query and update query  reference to the same source table, so i thought maybe better to use `post_operations {}` block.

I'm not sure if the update operation will wait until the incremental data inserting complete.

My questions is does post_operations {} will wait until incremental merge completed?   Thanks

Answer (score 1):

[According to this answer by Google staff on the Google Cloud Community](https://www.googlecloudcommunity.com/gc/Data-Analytics/post-operations-or-config-type-quot-operations-quot-in-GCP/m-p/611163/highlight/true#M2314), it's advisable to use `post_operations` here instead of `config { type: "operations" }`.

`post_operation` will wait until the incremental load is finished before executing. However, the `config { type: "operations" }` block doesn't necessarily wait until the incremental load is finished and could lead to the script starting before the incremental load is complete.